# rsyslog custom log file permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, services, rsyslog

I have haproxy service running on the server. For haproxy logging created following /etc/rsyslog.d/haproxy.conf file with content mentioned below:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
$UDPServerRun 514
$FileCreateMode 0600

local0.* /var/log/my-haproxy-2.log
```

I consider that with this configuration my-haproxy-2.log file permissions should be set 0600 but it is 0644.

Is there anything in the configuration that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

There have been changes in rsyslog over time, you could try to set `$umask 0077` as well as `$FileCreateMode 0600` ...